# GhostScript Unique Filenaming

Tags: ghostscript

I'm creating a virtual printer by using Redirection Port Monitor (Redmon) to pass a PostScript file to GhostScript and have it saved as a PDF.  Is there a parameter that I can use in the -sOutputFile= for it to save the pdf with a unique filename?  System Date and Time or even passing the original filename is fine.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no such parameter, you are expected to generate the output filename yourself.

If you set RedMon to 'prompt for filename' then that's the filename that GS will use. You might be able to set the environment variable REDMON_FILENAME and have it use that, not entirely sure.

You could alter RedMon to set the OutputFile= to a unique name, such as date and time, Ghostscript has no options to do so (and it can't use the input filename, because it doesn't know it).

Of course, you could also alter Ghostscript if you're going to change source code and rebuild applications.